# Integer value not incrementing

Tags: java, android

I am making a picture changing app, which will change pictures with animation when tapped. I am using the value of an integer to determine which code should be running using if statements. I am incrementing the value of my integer inside the if statement block but for some reasons, it is not happening (the incrementing, I checked using the logs). Can anyone give any idea of why I's value is not changing?

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void bbd(View view) {
    i = 1;
    Log.d(" value of i is ", String.valueOf(i));
    if (i == 1) {
        i++;
        ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById((R.id.cc));
        img2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bb);
        img.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

    } else if (i == 2) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bb);
        ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById((R.id.cc));
        img.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        img2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        i--;

    }
}
```

Comment: initialize `i` outside of method `bbd()`

Comment: Do you know what `i = 1;` does at the beginning of your method?

Comment: You set `i = 1;` so it will always go into `if (i == 1) {`

Comment: every time you call bbd method  i = 1; (i value you initializing 1) than its goes i==1 condition

Comment: oh yes! i didn`t noticed it, thanks everyone @AnkitLamba, @laalto, @notyou , @Venki WAR

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help only.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `bbd()` method, variable `i` receives `1`, in this case it will always go on `i==1` condition.

I think this kind of question should be discussed on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, right?